# How can i use resultTransformer in grails3

Tags: grails, grails3, grails-3.3

I want to transfer projection result into List.i'm using following code

```
testDataList = FunctionalTestCaseData.createCriteria().list(max: pageSize, offset: offset){
                eq("functionalTest",fTestcase)
                and{
                    eq("delFlag",0)
                }

                projections {
                    property('id')
                    property('testStep')
                    property('testData')
                    property('expectedResult')
                    property('actualResult')
                    property('result')
                    property('functionalTest')
                }
                resultTransformer = new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(FunctionalTestCaseData)
            };
```

but is doesn't work. its gives me `List<Domain>` with `null` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code is work for me.

```
domainDataList = DomainClass.createCriteria().list(){
            resultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP)
                    projections {
                        property('id', 'id')
                        property('title', 'title')
                    }
                };
```

Note: Use `property()` with two param,Otherwise it will return `null`.